# How can I access variables in setInterval

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, popupwindow

I'm showing a popup loading modal on my view page .. which is successfully showing and hiding  after a given time.

Here is my code:

```
function openSirenModal() {
    var timeout;

    $.modal({
        contentAlign: 'center',
        width: 240,
        title: 'Loading',
        content: '<div style="line-height: 25px; padding: 0 0 10px"><span id="modal-status">Contacting to the device...</span><br><span id="modal-progress">0%</span></div>',
        buttons: {},
        scrolling: false,
        actions: {
            'Cancel': {
                color: 'red',
                click: function (win) {
                    win.closeModal();
                }
            }
        },
        onOpen: function () {
            // Progress bar
            var progress = $('#modal-progress').progress(100, {
                size: 200,
                style: 'large',
                barClasses: ['anthracite-gradient', 'glossy'],
                stripes: true,
                darkStripes: false,
                showValue: false
            }),

                // Loading state
                loaded = 0,

                // Window
                win = $(this),

                // Status text
                status = $('#modal-status'),

                // Function to simulate loading
                simulateLoading = function () {


                    var siren = "siren"
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            value: siren
                        },
                        url: "http://localhost/siren/siren/",

                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data == 1) {                                    progress.hideProgressStripes().changeProgressBarColor('green-gradient');
                                status.text('success!');
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    win.closeModal();
                                }, 1500);

                            } else {
                                progress.hideProgressStripes().changeProgressBarColor('red-gradient');
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    win.closeModal();
                                }, 1500);

                                status.text('error!');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error");
                            progress.hideProgressStripes().changeProgressBarColor('red-gradient');
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                win.closeModal();
                            }, 1500);
                            status.text('error!');
                        }
                    });
                };

            // Start
            timeout = setTimeout(simulateLoading, 2500);
        },
        onClose: function () {
            // Stop simulated loading if needed
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    });
};
```

Above code successfully works.
Now I have added some code in ajax success function.
I'm not writing the whole code now but just pasting the code in which I have done some changes:

```
var siren = "siren";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        value: siren
    },
    url: "http://localhost/siren/siren/",

    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == 1) {

            var auto_refresh = setInterval(

            function () {
                $.get('siren/sirenjson', function (datas) {

                    if (datas == 1) {

                        $('#modal-progress').hideProgressStripes().changeProgressBarColor('green-gradient');
                        $('#modal-status').text('success!');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            clearInterval(auto_refresh);

                            * * win.closeModal(); * * //here i want to close the popup modal
                        }, 1500);    
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);    
        } else {
        }    
    },
```

Here I can't access the win variable and how can I access the woin variable so I can close the popup modal?

final code

```
function openSirenModal() {
   var timeout, win;
var progress;
var status;

$.modal({
    contentAlign: 'center',
    width: 240,
    title: 'Loading',
    content: '<div style="line-height: 25px; padding: 0 0 10px"><span id="modal-status">Contacting to the device...</span><br><span id="modal-progress">0%</span></div>',
    buttons: {},
    scrolling: false,
    actions: {
        'Cancel': {
            color: 'red',
            click: function (win) {
                win.closeModal();
            }
        }
    },
    onOpen: function () {
        // Progress bar
        var progress = $('#modal-progress').progress(100, {
            size: 200,
            style: 'large',
            barClasses: ['anthracite-gradient', 'glossy'],
            stripes: true,
            darkStripes: false,
            showValue: false
        }),

            // Loading state
            loaded = 0,

            // Window
            win = $(this),

            // Status text
            status = $('#modal-status'),

            // Function to simulate loading
            simulateLoading = function () {




            };

        // Start
        //timeout = setTimeout(simulateLoading, 2500);
    },


    onClose: function () {
        // Stop simulated loading if needed
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }


});

var siren = "siren";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        value: siren
    },
    url: "http://localhost/siren/siren/",

    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == 1) {

            var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function () {

                    $.get('siren/sirenjson', function (datas) {

                        if (data == 1) {

                            $('#modal-progress').hideProgressStripes().changeProgressBarColor('green-gradient');
                            $('#modal-status').text('success!');
                           setTimeout(function (win) {
          win.closeModal();
           clearInterval(auto_refresh);
      }, 1500,win);


                        }
                    });

                }, 1000);

            //modl.onClose;
            //alert('hello');



         } else {
            progress.hideProgressStripes().changeProgressBarColor('red-gradient');
            setTimeout(function () {
                win.closeModal();
            }, 1500);


            status.text('error!');
        }

        //clearTimeout(timeout);
    },
    error: function () {

        alert("error");
        progress.hideProgressStripes().changeProgressBarColor('red-gradient');
        setTimeout(function () {
            win.closeModal();
          }, 1500);
        status.text('error!');
    }
      });

  };
```

Comment: Can't you just declare the `win` variable in the `$(function)` scope, so that it is accessible to both modal and the ajax success?

Comment: Looking at the code you provided it looks like win is never declared with `var win=...` so when you set win to a value it's put on global scope (not a good idea). You should declare it somewhere so you can access it but not in global scope as kayen suggested. I will try to provide an example if I can copy and paste your code and remove the irrelevant part (90% of it)

Comment: help me in this code ..i just want to close the modal out ... just tell me where should i declare winm so i can access the window and close it

Comment: In the code provided you don't declare it anywhere but you could declare it where you declared timeout.

Comment: the code which @bryce provided me ? i have tried it ..but it isn't closing the modal

Comment: `var timeout, win;` that should do it.

Comment: @HMR i tried .. now this error is coming on the console.."Cannot call method 'closeModal' of undefined "

Comment: Do you have the complete code? What's posted above is not what's generating that error.

Comment: yup ..well let me upload it

Comment: i have posted my code here ... http://pastebin.com/4xxULLYa

Comment: Sorry, that's blocked here in China.

Comment: ok let me post here ....

Comment: you can check my final code which is i am trying

Answer (score 0):

Pass your parameters after the milliseconds argument:

```
setTimeout(function (win) {
    win.closeModal();
    clearInterval(auto_refresh);
}, 1500,win);
```

However, be aware that this method needs to be patched in with a polyfill [such as this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Callback_arguments) for use on Internet Explorer versions smaller than 10.

Comment: Or if you want it to work in IE; use the polyfil, pass a closure to setTimeout or use bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Callback_arguments But I think this scoping issue isn't solved then because win is not in the scope when setTimeout is called so kayen's comment could do the trick.

Comment: @BryceHanscomb i have tried ur code but it didnt work ..popup modal is not closing

Comment: @hellosheikh Most browsers have a console, you can open it by pressing F12. The console could show you some error or if you add some console.log statements to your code it could output of what your code is doing. When you apply that you could provide more helpful information other than `it doesn't work` and it would help you understand what your code is actually doing. console.log statements are very helpful with complicated code. Be ware that IE will throw an error on console.log unless you have the debug window open (F12)

Comment: @HMR there is an error coming on the console saying win is not defined

Comment: I don't know what to tell you - it's syntactically and functionally valid code that works for me.

Comment: hmm ... my console giving me this error    Cannot call method 'closeModal' of undefined "

Comment: @BryceHanscomb What the OP posted is that at some point it does: `win=$(this)` at that point the win variable is part of the global scope so the code posted above would not have the trouble of `win is undefined` I think the OP defines win in some sub function passed as an argument so it's out of scope when setTimeout is called.

Answer (score 0):

you close first your modal box then clear interval

now in your code clear interval exist first

so it stop and next code not executed so in this order problem

```
  clearInterval(auto_refresh);

                            * * win.closeModal(); * * //here i want to close the popup modal
```

**change in**

```
                                * * win.closeModal(); * * //here i want to close the popup modal
 clearInterval(auto_refresh);
```

Comment: then make win variable global

Comment: did it too ... after define globally and then when i run my code ...Cannot call method 'closeModal' of undefined " this eror comes on my console

Comment: is this dialog box in jquery ui

Comment: @Riturajratan win doesn't have to be global, you can declare it within the `openSirenModal` function right after timeout

Comment: then you can send win by function parameter   like var win  call(win); function call(win){ //in this function you can access your win variable };  iam just giving an idea not say like this way... hope this make sense

Comment: @Riturajratan check my final code ... you can see it what i am doing right now

Comment: you decalare win in openSirenModal() function please declare  out side of openSirenModal function  if you declare inside then in ajax request it cant access

Comment: @hellosheikh have you found your result or still in trouble

Comment: @Riturajratan sorry i didnt ur comment .. no again it showing me the same error ..not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35737/discussion-between-rituraj-ratan-and-hellosheikh)